# How can I export data from a foxpro database to excel(.xls)?

Tags: database, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I want to enter the data in FoxPro but save the data in .xls format.

Comment: This type of questions needs to be addressed on SuperUser.com instead.

Comment: Considering that the EXPORT command is in the VFP language reference, I'd say it's on topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977646(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `EXPORT TO *FILENAME* TYPE XLS`

Comment: Depending on some group polices your company may have in place, you may not be able to modify this type of file.  I suggest using `EXPORT TO "[INSERT FILE LOC AND NAME HERE"] XL5`

Answer (score 3):

COPY TO is more flexible: FIELDS LIKE or FIELDS EXCEPT.

But do use XL5, for newer Excel 5 format.  XLS creates XLS and users will be asked to change formats when they save with new Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you can use COPY TO and specify the specific fields and field sequence, something like

```
COPY TO SomeFileName fields MyFld1, MyFld2, MyFld3 type XLS
```

Answer (score -1):

for exmple ossep12.dbf file

```
COPY TO "c:\kbk.xls" NEXT 50000 FIELDS Ossep12.uniqueid,Ossep12.crmacct,Ossep12.billno,Ossep12.ll,Ossep12.bb,Ossep12.sc,Ossep12.st,Ossep12.os,Ossep12.bldt,Ossep12.classcode,Ossep12.acsubtype,Ossep12.name,Ossep12.add1,Ossep12.add2,Ossep12.add3,Ossep12.city,Ossep12.pin,Ossep12.inactdt,Ossep12.status,Ossep12.phone,Ossep12.exgcode,Ossep12.bldate,Ossep12.inactivedt TYPE XL5
```